# How does Entity Framework map to tables in SQL?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

How does EF handle the mapping to the SQL tables? I understand the general idea, but I changed the name of my model in C#, but it's still pointing to the table when using the context object. I expected it to break, but I am guessing it is cached somewhere? Is that how it is handled deep inside EF somewhere?

More detail: This is persistent when the console app stops, and then restarts. The model has a different name, but EF still somehow goes to the table.

Answer (score 0):

Well normally in an EF Core Project with EntityFrameworkCore you have a file called `ApplicationDbContextModalSnapshot` that describes the state of your entities and the SQL tables they map to http://prntscr.com/26lj4ow So in this file, which is updated with every migration, you can find code like this http://prntscr.com/26lj5lf

```
modelBuilder.Entity("Identity.Data.Domain.Locale", b =>
            {
                b.Property<Guid>("Id")
                    .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                    .HasColumnType("uniqueidentifier");

                b.Property<string>("Code")
                    .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

                b.Property<string>("Description")
                    .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

                b.Property<string>("Name")
                    .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

                b.HasKey("Id");

                b.ToTable("Locales");
            });
```

Here we are mapping an entity called `Identity.Data.Domain.Locale` to table `Locales`. If you change the entity model name from `Locale` to `LanguageLocale` and we update ApplicationDbContextModalSnapshot  we get `LanguageLocale` entity mapped to `Locales` table http://prntscr.com/26lj9dz

```
        modelBuilder.Entity("Identity.Data.Domain.LanguageLocale", b =>
            {
                b.Property<Guid>("Id")
                    .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                    .HasColumnType("uniqueidentifier");

                b.Property<string>("Code")
                    .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

                b.Property<string>("Description")
                    .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

                b.Property<string>("Name")
                    .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

                b.HasKey("Id");

                b.ToTable("Locales");
            });
```

In `ApplicationDbContext` `OnModelCreating` you can override the default entity model to table mapping (which is normally [EntityModelName] to SQL tables [EntityModelName**s**] with code similar to this

```
  foreach (var entityType in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
        {
            var table = entityType.GetTableName();
            entityType.SetTableName("Identity_" + table);
        }
```

Here we are setting a mapping to each entity in our project to map to SQL table with a name `Identity_[EntityName]`